# No Message Block in list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, messages

The message block is missing in list.phtml. If redirect to cart after product add is disabled, the customer will get no message. Simply adding the block in list.phtml won't work however.

Answer (score 1):

The message blocks should be added to all pages on the main page template. This happens via the layout handle `default` where the following children are added to the root level (see app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml).

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```

This means you can call these children on the root template level. These template are `1column.phtml` etc under the folder `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page`.

Comment: I see that this block is added in the page template files via
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>` but I use the same page template for product view as I am using for category view, why are my messages only displayed on my product view page?

Comment: @loeffel are these cart messages?

Comment: Cart messages, customer messages, add-to- messages. Basically everthing I tried sofar...